# Get value from attribute value from XML

Tags: android, android-styles, styleable

I have a custom class which is extened from Textview now I need to get the values in the xml for the layout. I tried

```
public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    int style =  attrs.getAttributeIntValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textStyle,-1);
    init(style);
}
```

but I can't get `com.android.internal.R.styleable` it says package don't exist. I think I can access it from out side the package.

Is there any way to get the style from xml here?

The value of `styleable.TextAppearance_textStyle` is -2001555 will this change or will I be able to get the correct value always by using?

```
int style =  attrs.getAttributeIntValue(-2001555,-1)
```

Comment: no, in the 99% of the case it will crash your application, since those id are build at compile time

Comment: so how do i get the AttributeSet value ?

Comment: See if this tutorial helps: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyr to get attribute values in this way. Pay attention to what [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) indices are, as described in docs.

```
public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int[] attrsArray = new int[]{android.R.attr.textStyle};
    final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
    int style = array.getInt(0, -1);  // returns 1 for bold, 2 for italic
    array.recycle();
}
```